# MacBook terminal failed with: -bash: __git_ps1: command not found

Tags: bash, terminal

While modifying `.bash_profile` in my MacBook using terminal, I may have made a mistake.

Right after saving the changes in `.bash_profile` whatever command I am trying to execute in terminal it responds with:

```
-bash: __git_ps1: command not found
```

As a result I can not reach to `.bash_profile` again to revert my changes. Any idea how to restore or resolve this problem?

Comment: You can use a non-terminal/GUI editor to change your bash_profile... or overwrite it with a good version.

Answer (score 0):

I found a the solutions from [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13081099/10037653).

- Open the terminal.
- Go to “File (or Shell) -> New Command.
- Type `open -e .bash_profile`
- Then hit run.

Comment: Nice self-solved issue! But can you add a link to the StackOverflow thread that solved your issue.

Comment: Solution found by this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13081099/10037653

Comment: Comments are not really the place for providing that info. I added it to your answer. That is where it should be added so all can read it.